# The meaning of error msgs in arm_navigation and how to debug

Tags: actionlib, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this tutorial

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmPoseGoal
```

and modified it slightly to make it move to four different positions.

Sometime errors happened such as:

```
Action failed: ACTIVE
Timed out achieving goal A
Action failed: PENDING
```

When error occurred, sometimes it still took the end-effector to the right place, while sometimes the arm wouldn't move. This is my code, it's almost the same as the one in the tutorial.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

#include <arm_navigation_msgs/MoveArmAction.h>
#include <arm_navigation_msgs/utils.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc!=4)
  {
      ROS_INFO("Wrong Argument : rosrun package binary_file x y z");
      return -1;
  }

  ros::init (argc, argv, "move_arm_pose_goal_test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<arm_navigation_msgs::MoveArmAction>     move_arm("move_right_arm",true);
  move_arm.waitForServer();
  ROS_INFO("Connected to server");
  arm_navigation_msgs::MoveArmGoal goalA;

  goalA.motion_plan_request.group_name = "right_arm";
  goalA.motion_plan_request.num_planning_attempts = 1;
  goalA.motion_plan_request.planner_id = std::string("");
  goalA.planner_service_name =     std::string("ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path");
  goalA.motion_plan_request.allowed_planning_time = ros::Duration(5.0);

  arm_navigation_msgs::SimplePoseConstraint desired_pose;
  desired_pose.header.frame_id = "torso_lift_link";
  desired_pose.link_name = "r_wrist_roll_link";
  desired_pose.pose.position.x = atof(argv[1]);
  desired_pose.pose.position.y = atof(argv[2]);
  desired_pose.pose.position.z = atof(argv[3]);

  desired_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  desired_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  desired_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
  desired_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

  desired_pose.absolute_position_tolerance.x = 0.02;
  desired_pose.absolute_position_tolerance.y = 0.02;
  desired_pose.absolute_position_tolerance.z = 0.02;

  desired_pose.absolute_roll_tolerance = 0.04;
  desired_pose.absolute_pitch_tolerance = 0.04;
  desired_pose.absolute_yaw_tolerance = 0.04;

      arm_navigation_msgs::addGoalConstraintToMoveArmGoal(desired_pose,goalA);

  if (nh.ok())
  {
    move_arm.sendGoal(goalA);
    if(move_arm.waitForResult(ros::Duration(200.0)))
    {
      move_arm.cancelGoal();
      ROS_INFO("Timed out achieving goal A");
    }
    else
    {
      actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = move_arm.getState();
      bool success = (state == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED);
      if(success)
        ROS_INFO("Action finished: %s",state.toString().c_str());
      else
        ROS_INFO("Action failed: %s",state.toString().c_str());
    }
  }
  ros::shutdown();
}
```

I would like to know what's the meaning of the errors :

PENDING
ACTIVE
RECALLED
REJECTED
PREEMPTED
ABORTED
SUCCEEDED
LOST

And how to debug using these error msgs.( the timeout msg as well)

Besides, why is that sometimes the arm can still move when the error occurred.

Thanks for any advise~

.----------------------------------------.

The four positions I've test :

./ik_arm_traj 0.5 0.0 -0.2

./ik_arm_traj 0.5 -0.4 -0.2

./ik_arm_traj 0.5 -0.4 0.2

./ik_arm_traj 0.5 0.0 0.2

```
---modified---
```

I've follow dornhege's advise and try to print out the result defined by MoveArm.action in arm_navigation_msgs.

```
ROS_INFO("Action result:%d", move_arm.getResult()->error_code.val)
```

However, the error code always be 0, no matter whether the arm can move or not.
So I still can't know what makes the move_arm action fail.

Besides, I would like to ask that since the move_arm is built on actionlib, how can the arm sometimes still moves while the status of the action server reported failed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48164/the-meaning-of-error-msgs-in-arm_navigation-and-how-to-debug/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The state is actually just the state that you get from actionlib and not specific to move_arm. This will only tell you if the action is running/succeeded/failed, etc.

To get detailed information about the move_arm result, look at the [MoveArmActionResult](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/move_arm_msgs/html/msg/MoveArmActionResult.html) that contains arm_navigation_msgs error codes.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-14**:
What's the different between the state of actionlib and the state of move_am in this situation, since the arm is controlled by the arctioblib of "move_right_arm" ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-14**:
actionlib is the generic action wrapper that can be any action. It is used to provide the specific move_arm action. This action defines its custom state/result. It is the same relationship as a ROS service call and the actual service definition.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-18**:
I've written a simple action server and find out that the status topic is of the type actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray, which is related to PENDING, ACTIVE, RECALLED, etc. However, I don't know how to write a program to print out the result, since the tutorial of actionlib also uses status as well.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-18**:
Any simple example or tutorial about how to print out the result? Thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-19**:
You get the result via the getResult() function (instead of getState()).

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-19**:
What is the return type of getResult()? In this example, the following code snippet get compile error:

arm_navigation_msgs::MoveArmActionResult * result=move_arm.getResult();

ROS_INFO("Action result: %d", result -> error_code.val);

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-19**:
@dornhege : please see the modified part of the original post. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dornhedge already answered the error code part of your question. So, I'll respond to why your arm keeps moving.

Actually, your example already hints the answer.

```
Action failed: ACTIVE
Timed out achieving goal A
Action failed: PENDING
```

Your action goal only failed, because it got timed out (go to A in X seconds).
However, move_arm uses another action server for executing arm motions (FollowJointTrajectoryAction). Unfortunately, move_arm does not cancel the execution action, once its own goal has been aborted/preempted. In your case that is not too bad, but in some cases you really want to stop the execution.

Have a look at [this Q&A](http://answers.ros.org/question/39257/interrupting-a-joint-trajectory/#44634) to find out how to cancel the execution, if you cancel a move_arm action.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1